# the bool parameter is wrong,given "false" ,but in the called function,the parameter is "true"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

i am using ndk to compile c++ code on android platform and ios platform.here is a function of a class 
header is:

```
enum FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_ID{
    FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_1 = 1,
    FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_2 = 1 << 1,
    FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_3 = 1 <<2,
    FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_MAX = 31,
};
class FunctionalSwitch{
public:
    FunctionalSwitch();
    virtual ~FunctionalSwitch();

public:
    void setFunctionalEnable(bool enable, int functionalID);
    bool isFunctionalEnable(int functionalID);
private:
    int m_ifunctionalBits;
};
```

.cpp file is

```
#include "FunctionalSwitch.h"
FunctionalSwitch::FunctionalSwitch():m_ifunctionalBits(0){

}

FunctionalSwitch::~FunctionalSwitch(){

}

void FunctionalSwitch::setFunctionalEnable(bool enable, int functionalID){
    if (enable) {
            m_ifunctionalBits |= functionalID;
    }else{
        m_ifunctionalBits &= (~functionalID);
    }
}
bool FunctionalSwitch::isFunctionalEnable(int functionalID){
    return m_ifunctionalBits & functionalID;
}
```

and use the class as a member in class called Global

```
class Global : Base
{
public:
    FunctionalSwitch& getFunctionalSwitch(){return m_oFunctionalSwitch;}
private:
    FunctionalSwitch m_oFunctionalSwitch;

};
```

and somewhere i called the function(this is a example,the code in my project is more complex)

```
Global a;
a.getFunctionalSwitch().setFunctionalEnable(false, FUNCTIONAL_SWITCH_2);
```

here is the question, the bool parameter i give is "false", but what the function get is "true", i have added some log, it is "true" in the log.
any idea to help me find out what happened.
this code works on xcode. but has problem on ndk